# CSS: Chrome ignores vertical "background-position" if "margin-top" is set

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image, background-position

I have a background image applied to `BODY` tag, with following rules (please, note "negative offset on vertical position"):

```
body 
{
    background-image: url("../images/body-bg.png");
    background-position: center -85px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If I add a `margin-top` on `body`, like this:

```
body 
{
    ...
    margin-top:40px;
}
```

**Firefox renders it correctly**, simply shifting all body content (included background) bottom by 40px.

**Chrome seems ignore offset only for background** (*content is shifted but background remain on top, like if `margin-top` does not exist*)

---

**EDIT AFTER MORE RESEARCHES**:

I made some tests and I discovered a strange behaviour.

*Wrong offset depends by an eventual background on HTML tag!*

Please, look a this [**jFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrypsax6/). If you remove `background-color:white;` from `HTML` tag, both browsers will offset (or not) `background-image` of `BODY` tag.

Can you explain me why?

Comment: First guess: I would try padding-top instead..

Comment: I already tried... for my needs is unfortunately not possible....

Comment: `If I add a margin-top on body` That suggests to me that you are going about this the wrong way, so I'd be presenting your reasons for doing this and asking for a better approach.

Comment: `margin-top` is present because I have to import a "3rd party header" on top of my website. So body is shifted down by 40px and this header is loaded as a `top:-40px` absolute position. It runs perfectly in Firefox but not in Chrome.